# Can I define a xacro with params by another xacro?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to define a xacro macro with another macro.
But I am getting an error about one of the internal params from the macro.
Is there an escape sequence or something for that?

Currently I get the error:

> raise XacroException("Property wasn't defined: %s" % str(ex))
> xacro.XacroException: Property wasn't defined: u'name'

```
<xacro:macro name="rr_mat_gaz_color_def" params="color material">
    <xacro:macro name="rr_mat_gaz_${color}" params="name material">
       <gazebo reference="${name}_link">
        <material value="${material}" />
       </gazebo>
    </xacro:macro>
</xacro:macro>
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204400/can-i-define-a-xacro-with-params-by-another-xacro?/) by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fairly certain you have to define the macros sequentially and not recursively.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-03-09**:
Me too, I just wanted to ask and see if I am right.